# Problems dynamically loading a Java class with Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jelly

I am porting a Jelly script to Groovy and I am stuck on one line of code from the Jelly script which implements the [new](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/tags.html#core%3anew) tag:

```
<j:new var="builder" classLoader="${it.class.classLoader}" className="hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.ContentBuilder"/>
```

I know this is loading a class, but I cannot get Groovy to do the same thing.  I have tried several different ways using various class loader examples I have found, but I always get error(s), typically something like "unable to resolve class".  One problem is that I don't know if I need to use a file system path:

```
C:\Jenkins\plugins\email-ext\WEB-INF\classes\hudson\plugins\emailext\ContentBuilder.class
```

Or if I need to use a URL (and I don't know the URL to the file nor do I know if Jenkins will let me access the file if I did know the URL).

**So the question is how do I instantiate** [hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/email-ext/2.7/email-ext-2.7-javadoc.jar!/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/ContentBuilder.html)

P.S. The old Jelly script and the new Groovy script are both being used as email templates with [Jenkins Email-Ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).  The Jelly script works, but I want it in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Why do I always figure it out right after I post the question?

```
    ClassLoader cl = it.class.getClassLoader()
    def builder = cl.loadClass("hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.ContentBuilder", true).newInstance()
```

Comment: What is `it` here in `it.class.getClassLoader()`? Can you explain your answer a little more please. `ClassLoader` is abstract and groovy also has a `GroovyClassLoader`. What implementation are you using? or does it even matter?

Comment: Wish I could help, but that was a long time ago and I don't have that code anymore. I would expect "it" was the build context maybe, but I'm not sure. Sorry.

Comment: I got it working by compiling and packing .java to .jar file. Then put it in the classpath of jenkins. Then used the import statement in jenkins groovy script and its working.

Comment: how did you put it in the classpath of jenkins, exactly? I've tried all kinds and I'm still not able to do it?=